# Can I use Amazon Rekognition video api without storing videos in S3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

All of Amazon documentation on their Video Rekognition API are examples of videos that are stored in S3 bucket. Is there anyone out there who have tried using the API without storing the videos in S3 i.e. on local machine or GCS?

Answer (score 1):

All **video-related** Amazon Rekognition API calls (eg `start_face_detection()` and `start_face_search()`) require input to be provided from Amazon S3.

Calls related to **still images** can alternatively be passed as a series of Bytes in the call.